# Can't run Node after install on EC2 Instance

Tags: node.js, bash, amazon-ec2

I followed the instructions here: https://codeforgeek.com/2015/05/setup-node-development-environment-amazon-ec2/ - Everything seems to have installed properly. When I run 'node --version' I get -bash: node: command not found. I have run sudo ln -fs out/Release/node /usr/bin/node and still the same issue. When I run 'whereis node' I get node: /usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node. When I navigate to either of these directories 'node' is in red.

I am a front end guy so all this infrastructure stuff is new to me so please excuse my ignorance. I would like to avoid smashing my machine!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [NodeSource packages](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora).

The setup script is https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x

If you just want it to work, as `root` run

```
sudo su - root
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
yum -y install nodejs gcc-c++ make
```

Comment: I tried that and get "error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (Permission denied)
Error executing command, exiting" I ran both commands as sudo

Comment: You need to be root for the `|` to work. Otherwise save the `setup_6.x` file somewhere and run it `sudo bash setup_6.x`